# Using custom field types in a ROS message

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it at all possible to construct a message containing fields with an arbitrary type?

For instance, I would like to create a message containing an array of type [pcl::Correspondence](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1_correspondence.html). Is this possible or would I have to convert this to a group of primitive objects first?

Bidski

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201236/using-custom-field-types-in-a-ros-message/) by [Bidski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20952/bidski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2015-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since ROS messages generate code for many languages, it isn't possible to use language-specific types within message.

You'll have to convert your types into ROS types.

You can also adapt C++ types for serialization (see: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes ), but this still doesn't allow them to be used within other messages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3